# How to stop a udp_server_loop from the outside

Tags: ruby, sockets, server, udp

I've written little UDP server in Ruby:

```rb
def listen
  puts "Started UDP server on #{@port}..."

  Socket.udp_server_loop(@port) do |message, message_source|
    puts "Got \"#{message}\" from #{message_source}"

    handle_incoming_message(message)
  end
end
```

I start it in a separate thread:

```rb
thread = Thread.new { listen }
```

Is there a way to gracefully stop the `udp_server_loop` from outside the thread without just killing it (`thread.kill`)? I also dont't want to stop it from the inside by receiving any UDP message. Is `udp_server_loop` maybe not the right tool for me?

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think you can do this with `udp_server_loop` (although you might be able to use some of the methods it uses). You are going to have to call [`IO::select`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-c-select) in a loop of your own with some way of signalling it to exit, and some way of waking the thread so you don’t have to send a packet to stop it.

A simple way would be to use the timeout option to `select` with a variable to set to indicate you want the thread to end, something like:

```
@halt_loop = false

def listen
  puts "Started UDP server on #{@port}..."
  sockets = Socket.udp_server_sockets(@port)

  loop do
    readable, _, _ = IO.select(sockets, nil, nil, 1) # timeout 1 sec
    break if @halt_loop
    next unless readable # select returns nil on timeout

    Socket.udp_server_recv(readable) do |message, message_source|
      puts "Got \"#{message}\" from #{message_source}"

      handle_incoming_message(message)
    end
  end
end
```

You then set `@halt_loop` to true when you want to stop the thread.

The downside to this is that it is effectively polling. If you decrease the timeout then you potentially do more work on an empty loop, and if you increase it you have to wait longer when stopping the thread.

Another, slightly more complex solution would be to use a [`pipe`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/IO.html#method-c-pipe) and have the select listen on it along with the sockets. You could then signal directly to finish the `select` and exit the thread.

```
@read, @write = IO.pipe
@halt_loop = false

def listen
  puts "Started UDP server on #{@port}..."
  sockets = Socket.udp_server_sockets(@port)
  sockets << @read

  loop do
    readable, _, _ = IO.select(sockets)
    break if @halt_loop

    readable.delete @read

    Socket.udp_server_recv(readable) do |message, message_source|
      puts "Got \"#{message}\" from #{message_source}"

      handle_incoming_message(message)
    end
  end
end

def end_loop
  @halt_loop = true
  @write.puts "STOP!"
end
```

To exit the thread you just call `end_loop` which sets the `@halt_loop` flag then writes to the pipe, making the other end readable and causing the other thread to return from `select`.

You could have this code check the readable `IO`s and exit if one of them is the read end of the pipe instead of using the variable, but at least on Linux there is a potential bug where a call to select might return a file descriptor as readable when it actuallt isn’t. I don’t know if Ruby deals with this, so better safe than sorry.

Also be sure to remove the pipe from the `readable` array before passing it to `udp_server_recv`. It’s not a socket so will cause an exception if you don’t.

A downside to this technique is that pipes are “[n]ot available on all platforms".

Answer (score 0):

Although I doubt I understand what would be wrong with [`Thread::kill`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Thread.html#class-Thread-label-Thread+termination) and/or `Thread#exit`, you might use the thread local variable for that.

```
def listen
  Socket.udp_server_loop(@port) do |message, message_source|
    break :interrupted if Thread.current[:break]
    handle_incoming_message(message)
  end
end
```

and do

```
thread[:break] = true
```

from the outside.

Comment: This only halts if the server receives a UDP packet, correct?

Comment: Correct. The block gets executed on the new messages only.

Comment: I'd rather want to stop it from inside the application without sending UDP packets.

Comment: I don't know how long `handle_incoming_message` takes. The thing I am searching for is semantically like: "kill the thread as soon as no message is being processed anymore"

Comment: Eh. How do you know there would not be any message anymore? That’s not how sockets work.

Comment: Maybe I indeed have a misunderstanding here. I thought that this would be the case as soon as `IO#select` blocks.

Comment: Imagine the client that sends UDP packets once per a second. `IO#select` blocks for a second every second. Should we terminate?

Comment: Yes, as soon as processing of the last package is complete.

Comment: There is no _last_ package.